# Header trouble while moving project from Overleaf V1 to V2

Tags: overleaf

I have a weird behavior of my header in a project that I moved from V1 to V2.

This picture show the result in V1: the Introduction is right after the table of codes. Everything works fine here.

[image]

Now, with the exact same project but in V2:

[image]

The header now shows "table of codes" on the left and "introduction" on the right. This goes on for the rest of the document : "table of codes" on every page. If I delete the table of codes from the main, the problem is the same but with the list of figures.

I am using the fancyheader package, here is the corresponding part of the latex code:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{27.06pt}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You are not showing all the relevant part of your code. Make a complete but small example.

Comment: My best guess would be that Overleaf v1 uses old packages versions while Overleaf v2 uses the packages ShareLaTeX used (newer versions).

Comment: Ok, I will stick to V1 then. Pity

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments